# Hiding a Particular set of cells in Gridview after comparing it with another cell - To give a Nested Look

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview

I have a following GridView

```
Day         Duty Office      Duty Officer

27/10/2013  Press                A
27/10/2013  Head Q               B
27/10/2013  Help Desk            D
28/10/2013  Press                A1
28/10/2013  Head Q               A2
28/10/2013  Medical              A3
28/10/2013  Help Desk            A4
29/10/2013  Press                B1
29/10/2013  Head Q               B2
29/10/2013  Medical              B3
29/10/2013  Help Desk            B4
```

Now if subsequent dates are same in Day column then I have to hide the subsequent dates , to be precise I got to show the columns in below manner.

```
Day         Duty Office      Duty Officer

27/10/2013  Press                A
            Head Q               B
            Help Desk            D
28/10/2013  Press                A1
            Head Q               A2
            Medical              A3
            Help Desk            A4
29/10/2013  Press                B1
            Head Q               B2
            Medical              B3
            Help Desk            B4
```

I wanted to try with something like this

```
 if (GridView1.Columns[0].Cells[i].Value.Equals(GridView1.Columns[0].Cells[i + 1].Value))
        {

            GridView1.Columns[0].Cells[i + 1].Value = "";
        }
```

but it is not working, Can anybody please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple approach:

I would declare a `List<string>` to hold distinct dates as string:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
```

Now in my gridview's rowdatabound, I will check if the date exists in the list. If it is, I will hide the cell. Else, I will add the date to my list.

**EDIT** 
 If you have same date in different places, and want to hide consecutive repeated dates only, you can try this approach:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string myValue = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
        if (myList.Contains(myValue))
        {
            e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            myList.Clear();//Make sure only following repeat will be effected
            myList.Add(myValue);
        }

    }
}
```

**Edit 2**

You can use a string instead of `List<string>`.  In the code at the beginning of the class add this:

```
string myString = string.Empty;
```

And in the RowDataBound:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string myValue = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
        if (myString == myValue)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {                
            myString = myValue;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I think If i go by this approach all the cells will be hidden. Because myList has all the date value present in DB.

Comment: It has just make sure that on date will be shown more than once. But if you repeat same date in more than once, try my edit.

Comment: Is it possible to go by this way: On the 1st column I parse through all the value in a fashion that..I store the first record in my list.Then if I find its repeat in following cell I make it invisible, again store in List when I get a new record.  I tried your snippet it is not working. :(

Comment: @Subhamoy - sorry to hear that it is not working for you. I test my code before posting. Only thing I can think, did you add this line at the beginning of your page `List<string> myList = new List<string>();` ?  I am editing my answer to what you suggested.

Comment: Hi I have sent you the code I am using to your Email ID. I have used Northwind sample database to test it. Can you check If I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: Thanks a Lot Afzal, The fix with the string value works.. :) I wish someday I will be a coder like you. :)